# Does any computable $T\supset PA^-$ have a provability predicate satisfying Hilbert-Berneys conditions?

Tags: logic, computability, provability

In the language of arithmetic, fix a computable theory $T\supset PA^-$. Let $P_T(x)$ be the usual $\Sigma_1$ formula: for any sentence $\varphi$, $\mathbb{N}\models P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$ iff there is a proof of $\varphi$ from $T$.

Here are the HB conditions:

$T\supset PA^-$ satisfies HB conditions with $P_T(x)$ iff for all sentences $\varphi,\psi$,

HB1 $T\vdash \varphi$ implies $T\vdash P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$

HB2 $T\vdash P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\rightarrow\psi\urcorner) \rightarrow(P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\rightarrow P_T(\ulcorner\psi\urcorner))$

HB3 $T\vdash P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\rightarrow P_T(\ulcorner P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\urcorner)$

I found some sources where it says any computable $T$ extending $PA^-$ with $P_T(x)$ satisfies HB1 and HB2. My concern is that all things I searched so far only says that any computable theory extending PA satisfies HB3 with this $P_T(x)$, instead of any computable theory extending $PA^-$. But in my thinking, HB3 should still be satisfied for any computable theory extending $PA^-$, so I am wondering if I am right.

Fix a comptuable $T\supset PA^-$ and fix a sentence $\varphi$. Then I think $T\vdash P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner) \rightarrow P_T(\ulcorner P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\urcorner)$. It suffices to show that $T\models P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner) \rightarrow P_T(\ulcorner P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\urcorner)$. Since $P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner) \rightarrow P_T(\ulcorner P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\urcorner)$ is still a $\Sigma_1$ sentence for a fixed $\ulcorner \varphi\urcorner$ as we can write numbers by using $1+\cdots+1$, it suffices to show that $\mathbb{N}\models P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner) \rightarrow P_T(\ulcorner P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\urcorner)$ because $\Sigma_1$ sentences go upwards. And this is clear from HB1: if $\mathbb{N}\models P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$, then $T\vdash \varphi$, so $T\vdash P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$, so $\mathbb{N}\models P_T(\ulcorner P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\urcorner)$.

Am I missing something, or am I correct?

Comment: Why is $P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner) \rightarrow P_T(\ulcorner P_T(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\urcorner)$ a $\Sigma_1$ sentence? Naively, it's $\Delta_2.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see. For some reason, I thought implication of $\Sigma_1$ sentences is still $\Sigma_1$, but I now see that this is false. Then how does HB3 hold if our theory is extending PA? I assume you would use the induction... but how you would use isn't clear to me.

Comment: HB3 is HB1, only formalized in T. So you need to think about the proof of HB1. Basically, we say $\varphi$ has a proof, and that proof has some Godel number $k,$ and then since $T$ proves all true $\Delta_0$ statements, it proves $Pr_T(k,\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner).$ This is actually pretty involved to formalize! Surely some induction will be needed to prove things like "$T$ proves all true $\Delta_0$ statements". (This isn't the only way, and perhaps isn't the most straightforward way, but similar things will come up no matter how you do it.)

Comment: Mistyped above, should have said $\Delta_1,$ not $\Delta_0.$ It's actually a bit difficult to find a proof of HB3 in any kind of detail... pretty much every reference of the 'introduction to Godel' genre punts on it, sometimes remarking that it requires some induction in $T$ ($\Sigma_1$-induction suffices). One reference is  Boolos *The Logic of Provability*, chapter 2.

Comment: Yes, Boolos textbook justification convinces me, thanks!